# git fails to perform any task

Tags: git

I am using Git on Windows 7 that I had downloaded from http://git-scm.com/download. No matter how many times I reinstall Git and try to do something (even clone doesn't work) it fails to perform any task at all. It always throws the same error:

```
fatal: Full write to remote helper failed: Invalid argument
```

I am at my wit's end to figure out what the hell does this even mean. No web search has revealed any definite solution to this mess. I have come across several errors on the net but this error hasn't seem to surface on anybody's system till now. Please help as I am a newbie.

Comment: Is this **any** task at all or any remote task?

Comment: Whenever I am trying to perform a task that requires remote access, such as clone or push or pull, the same error is thrown. And the error doesn't occur on a particular remote repository, but all repositories. So I think the Git in my system might be corrupted. Then again I have downloaded the latest stable version from the link mentioned above. Is the size of a file in the local repository creating an issue as I have heard that there is a certain limit to which Git can transfer files? If that's true, how do I modify the size limit?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was COMODO Antivirus that was silently blocking execution of git scripts. Add entire git installation folder to antivirus software exceptions list and it should start working.

Comment: Couldn't figure this one out for the longest time. Curse you Comodo for keeping me safe!