# fatal: Full write to remote helper failed: Invalid argument Done

Tags: git, github

This issue is making me crazy, I've installed Git Exensions, GitHub and even SourceTree on Win 64bit but I cannot pull / push anything, always receiving the bellow errors. I can clone public repos but then I try to sync I am stuck again.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" pull --progress "origin" 
fatal: Full write to remote helper failed: Invalid argument
Done
```

SourceTree error

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
fatal: Full write to remote helper failed: Invalid argument

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned the origin of that error message in "[Git push gives Error reading command stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19190416/6309)".

- If it is limited to a specific repo, it can be an issue on the remote side (like GitHub having trouble servicing some repos)
- If it is for *any* repo, check your antivirus to see if it isn't blocking `git.exe`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20567563/6309).
- you can see also that error message (as in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372179/git-head-commit-in-remote-repository-is-crap-how-exactly-should-i-go-about-r#comment13375879_10372247)) when the remote repo has `receive.denyNonFastForwards` set in its config.

I suggested that the installed Git the didn't work with the GUI.
The goal is to see if [the portable one](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount), once referenced by the OP's `%PATH%`, works better when called by the GUI apps.

The [OP Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582962/jim) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626173/fatal-full-write-to-remote-helper-failed-invalid-argument-done/20628001#comment31001178_20628001):

> It partially solved my problem.
>   SourceTree start working after re-downloading portable Git.

Comment: I am testing the GitHub on Win7 on another PC with the same repo's and It sync(pull/push) without any issue... Is there a chance that other Git apps are conflicting ?

Comment: @Jim try uncompressing a portable Git installation (https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount), and adding that in your %PATH%, in first position, in order to see if the issue persists in command line.

Comment: I check that without downloading the above Git installation (which apparantly has been installed previously with some of the above packages) I can sync flawless with repo via cmd... but not through Soft GUI

Comment: @Jim iok try to remove (uninstall) the "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\`", and add your portable version in your path, then.

Comment: Why?.... As I mention I didnt used the portable version but installed one which is working fine.... but not the GUI apps...

Comment: @Jim because the installed one doesn't work with the GUI. The goal is to see if the portable one, once reference by your `%PATH%` works better when called by the GUI apps.

Comment: I am marking it as answered because it is partially solved my problem... SourceTree start working after re-downloading portable Git . Thanks

Comment: @Jim Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.